# Angular-ui-grid : Disable on-click sort for the header cells

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angularjs-ng-click

I want to disable the sort for on-click event of the header cell and the sort option should only be available in the header drop down menu. I have tried using enableSorting property to disable to sort for on-click event. But, it is also removing the sort option from the header drop down too.

Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/J6XnIAb7E3MZe62Ixax3?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions1" class="grid"></div>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'gender' },
      { field: 'company', enableSorting: false }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Looking through the source on github (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/src/js/core/directives/ui-grid-header-cell.js) it doesn't look like this is supported yet, was hoping to do it myself. All or nothing via enableSorting which is a shame if you want to instead trigger the menu on clicking the entire header cell. (which is what I was attempting) Next means to attempt is via a completely custom menu.

Comment: I have tried to make the similar changes as you have attempted. But it is not very effective. Here is the pluncker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/bOTbU3Junq0DYmAsn0uv?p=preview

Comment: Yeah looks like it's a bittuva rabbit hole. First implement the header cell specified for the column you're working on, then replace the built-in icon via that same template. If you really need custom drop down menu with controls embedded in it (I do in this case) you will probably have to use another component like angular ui-select or type ahead, it varies based on the needs of the field.

Comment: My primary requirement is to make the drop down menu to appear on hover of the header cell.

Comment: if this is all you need, I would replace the template with a slightly-tweaked version, using ng-mouseover and calling on uiGridColumnMenu#showMenu (see http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.directive:uiGridColumnMenu#methods_showmenu) I have not done this myself though so don't have much else to add yet.